# XHTML namespacing benefits

Tags: xml, xhtml, xml-namespaces

I'm curious does XHTML namespacing like describing [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html) have some benefits in comparison using classes or data-* attributes.
I know that it's very powerful tool, but who can explain the advantages over using attributes in real world web-applications.

I would be great, if anyone can write example and point benefits.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It lets you use existing XML applications (such as SVG or MathML) and allows you to process data with standard XML tools instead of specialist HTML tools.

Comment: Hi! I'm asking a real benefit of using namespace in comparison using classes or data-* attributes. For example, link provided in question.

Comment: I'm not imagining the benefits listed in my answer.